# How to create your own non system Clipboard?

Tags: delphi, clipboard

Is it possible, and if so how would you go about implementing your own clipboard?

By this I mean be able to Copy and Paste anything to and from it just like the Windows clipboard does, but without actually interfering with the system clipboard.

To give a better idea this is what I tried:

```
uses
  ClipBrd;

...

procedure TMainForm.actCopyExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyClipboard: TClipboard;
begin
  MyClipboard := TClipboard.Create;
  try
    MyClipboard.AsText := 'Copy this text';
  finally
    MyClipboard.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That works in that it will copy the string "Copy this text" to the clipboard, but it overwrites whatever was on the Windows clipboard.

The above must just create an instance of the Windows clipboard, not actually creating your own.

Note that the custom clipboard could hold any data not just plain text. It should work just the same as the Windows clipboard, but without interfering with it (losing whatever was on it).

How could this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: You should do `Clipboard.AsText := 'Copy this text';`; there is no need to create a new instance of `TClipboard`.

Comment: Yes, but I want my own clipboard, not the Windows one.

Comment: Yes, I know. My comment was off-topic.

Comment: Ok I see, I used my own Clipboard instance to illustrate this example - otherwise you are correct I can just use Clipboard.AsText normally :)

Comment: There is only *the Windows clipboard*. There is no such thing as 'an instance of' it. The `TClipboard` is merely the VCL wrapper for the Windows Clipboard API. It is supposed to be used as a singleton class, as per my first comment.

Comment: Create a list and put things into it when you copy, take them out again when you paste.

Comment: And if you create another windows clipboard, what it will be it's use? Is like copying something in word and can not paste in excel, notepad, etc...what is the goal for this? an application independent of the OS? OS was concepted to interact with other application, but in the same time to give them as much 'freedom' as it can have...

Comment: @RBA just like Paste Special works in some applications. Lets say I have my own custom object types that I want to copy and paste in my application, without affecting the system clipboard.

Comment: And who keeps downvoting me? I don't understand why my questions keep getting negative responses??

Comment: To me this question sounds like: `"I'd like to create a wheel, just like a wheel, but it shouldn't be a wheel"`. Ergh, if it's round and works like a wheel then it's a wheel. Please explain WHY you think you need your own private clipboard, because as it stands you're just trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Paste Special simply allows you to select from the available formats in the windows clipboard. You can implement paste special on top of the windows clipboard. A better analogue would be office clipboard from older offices which stores multiple distinct items.

Comment: If you just want to have special processing for your own types, then RegisterClipboardFormat is the way to go and @Ken 's answer is the way to go. That way you could also (if applicable) copy and paste between instances of your own application using the system clipboard.

Comment: Is your problem fixed, please share!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is confusing; you say you want to do it without affecting the system clipboard, but then (from your own comment to your question) you seem to be wanting to implement something like MS Office's `Paste Special`.

If it's the first, as others have said you can't do that using the `TClipboard` wrapper; you have to implement your own, and passing information between applications will be very difficult.

If it's the second, you do this by using the Windows API [RegisterClipboardFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to define your own format.

```
type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
    YourCustomFormat: Word;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

constructor TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  YourCustomFormat := RegisterClipboardFormat('Your Custom Format Name');
end;
```

To put info into the clipboard in a custom format, you have to use [GlobalAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GlobalLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to allocate and lock a global memory block, copy your data into that block, unlock the block using [GlobalUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use `TClipboard.SetAsHandle` to transfer the memory block into the clipboard. You then need to then call [GlobalFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to free the memory block.

To retrieve things in your custom format, you do basically the same thing with a couple of steps reversed. You use GlobalAlloc/GlobalLock as before, use `TClipboard.GetAsHandle` to retrieve the clipboard's content, copy it into a local variable, and then call GlobalFree.

Here's an old example of putting a custom format (in this case, RTF text) into the clipboard - it's from a [newsgroup post](http://codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/592870/waArticleBookmark.2058475) by Dr. Peter Below of [TeamB](http://www.teamb.com). (The code and formatting are his from the original post; I've not tested it or even compiled it.) Reversing the process to get it back out should be clear from my instructions on what to change above, and I leave that to you to work out. :)

```
procedure TForm1.BtnSetRTFClick(Sender: TObject);
Const
  testtext: PChar = '{\rtf1\ansi\pard\plain 12{\ul 44444}}';
  testtext2: PChar = '{\rtf1\ansi'+
  '\deff4\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f4\froman\fcharset0\fprq2 Times New Roman;}}'
                     +'\pard\plain 12{\ul 44444}}';
  flap: Boolean = False;
Var
  MemHandle: THandle;
  rtfstring: PChar;
begin
    If flap Then
      rtfstring := testtext2
    Else
      rtfstring := testtext;
    flap := not flap;
    MemHandle := GlobalAlloc( GHND or GMEM_SHARE, StrLen(rtfstring)+1 );
    If MemHandle <> 0 Then Begin
      try
        StrCopy( GlobalLock( MemHandle ), rtfstring );
        GlobalUnlock( MemHandle );
        With Clipboard Do Begin
          Open;
          try
            AsText := '1244444';
            SetAsHandle( CF_RTF, MemHandle );
          finally
            Close;
          end;
        End;
      Finally
        GlobalFree( MemHandle );
      End;
    End
    Else
      MessageDlg('Global Alloc failed!',
                 mtError, [mbOK], 0 );
end;
```

Comment: +1 RegisterClipboardFormat does seem the way to go for @Blobby

Comment: Unlikely an indeed authoritative doctor's (he's a doctor yet?) code which performs **copy** as RTF fragment (not a private format at all) will solve *hypothetical* OP's problem with **paste special**.

Comment: RTF is not a predefined clipboard format whearas `Text` is (CF_OEMTEXT or CF_TEXT or CF_UNICODETEXT): It must be implemented as a custom clipboard format if WinAPI is the way to go. EasyGPS uses the `gpx` custom format which is in fact XML (Text).

Comment: I ran into a problem with a custom format where I wasn't seeing it on the paste end. This is because I was using the line `GlobalFree( MemHandle );` in copy which was freeing up my handle before I pointed to it's data on the paste end. Probably doesn't apply when just copying standard formats like text. A bit specific but maybe this information will help some people!

Answer (score 2):

You should define your own custom Clipboard. It may look something like this:

```
type
  TMyCustomClipboard = class
  private
    FStream: TMemoryStream;
    function GetAsText: string;
    procedure SetAsText(const Value: string);
    ...
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Clear;
    property AsText: string read GetAsText write SetAsText;
    procedure AsAnyThing: AnyType read GetAsAnyThing write AsAnyThing;
    ...
  end;
```

Then you can use `FStream` as custom clipboard container. You can store (Copy) any data inside that stream and use(Paste) it when you need it. You just need to write some Get/Set methods for your data types.

Comment: Interesting post thanks for providing a sample of how it could be achieved

Comment: In the ideal world it should be like that, abstract base TClipboard, then WinAPI concrete descendant and X/freedesktop concrete descendant, so on...

Answer (score 1):

TClipboard is a class incapsulating system clipboard, so you can't use it to instantiate another copy of a clipboard. You should implement your own class, representing a universal buffer with setters and getters.

Comment: And this is not entirely trivial, although certainly doable.

Comment: It depends. If you want to "understand" each data types, supported by your custom clipboard, then this is not trivial. But you possibly can admit to store and restore data just "as is" (say, as a binary stream), provided that cliboard clients "know", what they set and get.

Comment: Well, another instance of TClipboard is will behave just like one Clipboard function returns. So, extending TClipboard will require some hooking of this function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You can have an internal memory buffer that you move data into and out of, you can call it "copy" and "paste" if you want, but don't put it in the user interface that way, or you'll just confuse your users. There is only one system clipboard, and you cannot put data in it without affecting other programs.  If your next thought is to save the clipboard, overwrite with your stuff, then restore the original contents, don't bother.